How do you read the expression [Type, AnotherType]?
In typescript, I'm hovering over the method useSearchParams().
The tooltip shows the following info:

(alias) useSearchParams(defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams]

I am able to read it as:

The userSearchParams method accepts the optional parameter defaultInit with type URLSearchParamsInit and return an array of [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams]?

How do we read [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams]?
Is it an array consisting of URLSearchParams and SetURLSearchParams?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Wow, thank you! So [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams] is a tuple type array, a fixed array with index 0 being URLSearchParams, and index 1 being SetURLSearchParams. Thank for the link as well.
